# Proof for the Mass gap of non-chiral Luttinger liquids with a Cosine potential

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, string-theory, research-level, instantons

Similar to [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/116740/proof-for-the-mass-gap-of-sine-gordon-action-with-g-cos-beta-phi), I believe in condensed matter, people know the mass-gap statement for non-chiral Luttinger liquids with large $g \cos(\beta_{}^{} \cdot\phi_{})$ potential.

This is the sine-Gordon-like action for non-chiral Luttinger liquids with scaler fields $ \phi, \theta$:
$$
\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{ \mathcal{M}^2} dt \; dx \; k\, (\partial_t \phi \cdot \partial_x \theta+\partial_t  \theta  \cdot \partial_x \phi)  
+   g \cos(\beta_{}^{} \cdot\phi_{}) \\
- (v_{\phi,\phi}\partial_x \phi \cdot \partial_x \phi+v_{\phi,\theta }\partial_x \phi \cdot \partial_x \theta + v_{\theta ,\theta }\partial_x \theta \cdot  \partial_x \theta )
$$
Here $\mathcal{M}^2$ is a 1+1 dimensional spacetime manifold, where 1D space is a $S^1$ circle of length $L$. The velocity matrices $v$ are not crucial to the argument below.

> Q1: What is the original Ref which states and **proves this statement about the nonzero (or large) mass gap for both scaler fields $\phi, \theta$ at large $g$ coupling**?

-

> Q2: What is the **proof argument for the mass gap $m$ for large $g$**?